# What is the reason for 2 qubits no longer being entangled after interaction with a causality violating qubit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

**Background** : 
I was reading the following paper on [closed timelike curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_timelike_curve) ( CTC ) : [Quantum Mechanics Near Closed Timelike Curves](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4870). The [Deutsch  consistency equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics_of_time_travel#Deutsch.27s_prescription) for CTC is
$$\rho_{CTC}=Tr_{CR}( U \rho_{CR} \otimes \rho_{CTC} U^{\dagger})....(1)$$
$$\rho_{CR^{'}}=Tr_{CTC}( U \rho_{CR} \otimes \rho_{CTC} U^{\dagger})....(2)$$
here $\rho_{CTC}$ and $\rho_{CR}$ are density operators for the causality violating ( CTC ) and causality respecting systems ( CR ) respectively and $U$ in the unitary acting upon the composite system. $\rho_{CR^{'}}$ is the density operator describing the causality respecting sytem after the interaction.

**My doubt** : 
In the paper mentioned above they take $\rho_{CR}=|\psi \rangle \langle \psi|$ where $|\psi\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle$) and  $U=H \otimes I_4$ where $H$ is Hadamard operator on a qubit and $I_4$ identity in a 4-dimensional hilbert space ( that is the operator acts on the composite system described by second qubit of entagled state and a CTC qubit ). Then equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are used to get  $\rho_{CR^{'}}=\frac{I_4}{4}$ and $\rho_{CTC}=\frac{I_2}{2}.$
 It is thus seen that the state of the two causality respecting qubits after interaction is $\frac{I_4}{4}=\frac{I_2}{2} \otimes \frac{I_2}{2}$ ie. they are no longer entangled anymore. I am comfortable with solving and getting this but the author says that the fact that the two qubits are no longer entangled is evident. I quote the lines from the paper

> " the reduced density matrix of the CR qubits is found to be mixed after
>    the interaction, this is an expected result. It is known that according to
>    the monogamy property of entanglement, if two qubits are maximally
>    entangled, they cannot be entangled with a third qubit "

I am unable to understand why the above is the reason for qubits being no longer entangled.